# Malformed android manifest violating terms

Tags: android, android-manifest, receiver

I just got an email from Google Play, notifying me that my app will be removed as "we have determined that your app has a malformed AndroidManifest.xml file which may make it difficult for users to uninstall the app"

The app is plain simple: sends the device to standby.

Here is their recommendation

> In particular, the app’s AndroidManifest.xml contains a malformed Device Admin receiver entry (as identified by meta-data named android.app.device_admin). To be a well-formed Device Admin, the entry must declare an Intent filter for Intents with action android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED. The suggested modification is to make the entry well-formed if the receiver is a Device Admin, or remove the meta-data named android.app.device_admin if the receiver is not a Device Admin.

And here is the part from Android manifest

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAdmin"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@layout/policies" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" >
                    </action>
                </intent-filter>
            </meta-data>
        </receiver>
```

To be honest, I don't understand how to fix it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you've nested `<intent-filter>...</intent-filter>` under the meta-data tag, whereas both should be direct children of `<receiver />`. According to the documentation, a valid declaration should look as follows:

```
<receiver>
    <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
    <meta-data />
</receiver>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I have made the changes and uploaded the new apk. Let's hope it works